# show that the function $f$ is the solution to the partial differential equation.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Given that $f(x,y)=\phi(xy)$ where $\phi(xy):\Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$ is a differentiable function. Show that $f$ is the solution to the equation: $$\frac{1}{x} \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}} - \frac{1}{y} \frac{\partial {f}}{\partial{x}}=0$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function, and for any $a\in \mathbb{R}$ let $\phi_a:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $\phi_a(t)=\phi(at)$. Then you have $\phi_a'(t)=a\phi'(at)$. By definition of partial derivative, you now have
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x,y)=\phi_{y}'(x)=y\phi'(xy),$$
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} (x,y)=\phi_{x}'(y)=x\phi'(xy).$$
Therefore, the identity follows.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} &=& \frac{d\phi}{dz} (z=xy) x\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &=& \frac{d\phi}{dz} (z=xy) y\\
\frac{1}{x} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} &=& \frac{d\phi}{dz} (z=xy)\\
\frac{1}{y} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &=& \frac{d\phi}{dz} (z=xy)\\
\end{eqnarray*}